# iPhone Drawing to Screen Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I added a toolbar to the bottom which disappears while you are drawing, but I am unable to draw to the bottom of the screen.  I tried bounds or frame, but neither worked.  I only have one view, btw.  Too much drawing around the bottom will cause the whole picture around

[image: Picture of Problem]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    drawImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    drawImage.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:drawImage];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    mouseMoved = 0;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    toolbar.hidden = YES;   

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    lastPoint.y -= 20;

}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.y -= 20;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame
                                .size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;

    mouseMoved++;

    if (mouseMoved == 10) {
        mouseMoved = 0;
    }

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        toolbar.hidden = NO;
        drawImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }


    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 5.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you specify the frame size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set

```
 lastPoint.y -= 0;
```

and

```
currentPoint.y -= 0;
```

This works for me